# Expo-AV play audios after another

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, expo-av

I'm using Expo-AV and I'm trying to find a simple way to play 3 audio files after another.

I can't find anything online, does anyone have experience with Expo-AV?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The [docs for expo-av](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/av/) show an example that plays from a playlist of media. It's a bit of a wordy example since it covers a lot of cases, but it does what you want it to do.

[This line](https://github.com/expo/playlist-example/blob/cde89fd6fa338d263370e39dabbaa83fa80e13df/App.js#L215) shows how they initialize `Audio.Sound.createAsync` - the third argument is a callback that runs when the playback state changes. In that callback, you can check if the audio has finished playing, and play the next sound if so. The example does this [here](https://github.com/expo/playlist-example/blob/cde89fd6fa338d263370e39dabbaa83fa80e13df/App.js#L264).