# Expo-AV wait until audio finished playing

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, expo-av

I've been trying to fix this for over a week now and I just can't solve it.

I want to be able to map through an array of data that has a link for an audio file, and play each audio after another. The way I have it in my code now just plays all audios at once, so it doesn't wait until one is finished.

I know there are a couple ways you can wait until it finished playing, I just can't figure out how to use it. :/

Some help or a solution would be SUPER appreciated.

This is my code:

```
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
  ScrollView,
} from 'react-native';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Audio } from 'expo-av';
import Sura from '../components/sura';
import Data from '../data/data';
import englishTranslation from '../data/english';

const bookPage = (props) => {
  const [listView, setListView] = useState(true);
  const [ayahData, setAyahData] = useState([]);
  const [sound, setSound] = useState(null);
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    return sound
      ? () => {
          sound.unloadAsync();
        }
      : undefined;
  }, [sound]);

  async function playSound(soundURL) {
    const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync({
      uri: soundURL,
    });
    setSound(sound);

    await sound.playAsync();
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.background}>
      <View
        style={{ flex: 0.47, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}
      >
        <Image style={styles.image} source={require('../public/read.png')} />
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            props.modal(false);
          }}
          style={styles.goBackTouchable}
        >
          <Image
            style={styles.goBackView}
            source={require('../public/incorrect-button-compressed.png')}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View style={{ flex: 0.55 }}>
        <ScrollView
          style={styles.list}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        >
          {listView
            ? Data.data.surahs.map((el, i) => {
                return (
                  <Sura
                    setAyahData={setAyahData}
                    listView={setListView}
                    ayahs={el.ayahs}
                    setNumber={setNumber}
                    number={el.number}
                    title={`${el.number}.  ${el.englishName}`}
                    arabic={`${el.name}`}
                    key={i}
                  />
                );
              })
            : ayahData[0].map((el, i) => {
                return (
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => {
                      playSound(el.audio);
                    }}
                    key={i}
                    style={styles.ayahText}
                  >
                    <View>
                      <Text>
                        <Text style={styles.number}>{el.number}</Text>
                        {'\n'}
                        <Text style={styles.arabic}>{el.text}</Text>
                      </Text>
                    </View>
                    <View>
                      <Text style={styles.english}>
                        {
                          englishTranslation.data.surahs[number - 1].ayahs[i]
                            .text
                        }
                      </Text>
                    </View>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                );
              })}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default bookPage;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  background: {
    flex: 1,
    position: 'relative',
    backgroundColor: '#3f1f7e',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  goBackView: {
    top: 30,
    right: 15,
    position: 'absolute',
    width: 25,
    height: 25,
  },
  goBackTouchable: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 25,
    right: '-50%',
  },
  image: {
    position: 'absolute',
    width: '100%',
    height: '75%',
  },
  list: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
  },
  ayahText: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 150,
    marginBottom: 25,
    backgroundColor: '#2a195b',
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 5 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowRadius: 2,
  },
  arabic: {
    color: 'white',
    marginLeft: 50,
    marginTop: 25,
    fontSize: 15,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  number: {
    color: 'white',
    marginLeft: 25,
    marginTop: 25,
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: '100',
  },
  english: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 10,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
});
```

Example for the data:

```
                "ayahs": [
                    {
                        "number": 1,
                        "audio": "https://cdn.islamic.network/quran/audio/128/ar.alafasy/1.mp3",
                        "audioSecondary": [
                            "https://cdn2.islamic.network/quran/audio/128/ar.alafasy/1.mp3",
                            "https://cdn.islamic.network/quran/audio/64/ar.alafasy/1.mp3",
                            "https://cdn2.islamic.network/quran/audio/64/ar.alafasy/1.mp3"
                        ],
                        "text": "بِسْمِ ٱللَّهِ ٱلرَّحْمَٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ",
                        "numberInSurah": 1,
                        "juz": 1,
                        "manzil": 1,
                        "page": 1,
                        "ruku": 1,
                        "hizbQuarter": 1,
                        "sajda": false
                    },
                    {
                        "number": 2,
                        "audio": "https://cdn.islamic.network/quran/audio/128/ar.alafasy/2.mp3",
                        "audioSecondary": [
                            "https://cdn2.islamic.network/quran/audio/128/ar.alafasy/2.mp3",
                            "https://cdn.islamic.network/quran/audio/64/ar.alafasy/2.mp3",
                            "https://cdn2.islamic.network/quran/audio/64/ar.alafasy/2.mp3"
                        ],
                        "text": "ٱلْحَمْدُ لِلَّهِ رَبِّ ٱلْعَٰلَمِينَ",
                        "numberInSurah": 2,
                        "juz": 1,
                        "manzil": 1,
                        "page": 1,
                        "ruku": 1,
                        "hizbQuarter": 1,
                        "sajda": false
                    }
]
```

Comment: I dont know if this bumps up the question, but any help? :/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73095201/10718641 I answered a similar question here

Comment: hey @Abe, thank you so much for your answer. I looked through the documentation you provided, and it seems like its exactly what I need, however I just cant seem to implement it in my codebase

Could you give me a few hints or push me in the right direction please? It would be super appreciated

Comment: could you edit your post with the problems you're having?  hard to help without knowing where you're getting stuck

Comment: I basically just don't know how to listen for sound ending with my current code base, I added some comments in the code @Abe

Comment: https://github.com/expo/playlist-example/blob/cde89fd6fa338d263370e39dabbaa83fa80e13df/App.js#L215

Comment: this is the part I dont get, since I'm using functional react components, do I create useStates instead of constructors then? (For the this._onPlaybackStatusUpdate)

and even if I do, how would it be able to set my PlayBackStatus useState once it finished playing

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about constructors. You can use useState to keep track of the playback status.  You pass your callback to Audio.Sound.createAsync, and then set the state from inside the callback, like they do here: https://github.com/expo/playlist-example/blob/cde89fd6fa338d263370e39dabbaa83fa80e13df/App.js#L250

Comment: It makes a little bit more sense to me now thank you, I added some code to my inital post, could you please check @Abe so much appreciated

Comment: it's saying status.isLoaded is undefined

Comment: The problem is that you're invoking the function when you mean to pass it.  You're writing `onPlaybackStatusUpdate(status)` when you pass the function to loadAsync.  Putting the `(status)` after the name of the function invokes it. The callback you pass will be called with the status, so don't call it here.  The line should read instead `const { status } = await playbackObj.loadAsync({ uri: soundURL }, { shouldPlay: true }, onPlaybackStatusUpdate);`

Comment: thank you so much for your continous help @Abe, I dont have an error anymore and I feel like its very close but the audio isn't playing atm

Comment: I changed the code to what it looks like currently (so added your implementation without calling the function)

Comment: @Abe I updated my code again, it works when I manually click on the Touchable now, but it still wont work automatically. (I took out the playback part)

Comment: Nice! It's probably not playing because it's not loaded yet.

Comment: no thats not the reason, the logic for the automatically playing them after each other just isnt there yet. I give up for now