Detect when an audio has finished being produced with expo-av
I have this function in react-native with expo-av
  const [currentSound, setCurrentSound] = useState<Audio.Sound | null>(null)
  const [playingIndex, setPlayingIndex] = useState<number | null>(null)
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying]       = useState<boolean>(false)

const PLAY = async(uri: string, index: number) =>
  {
    if(currentSound) 
    {
      await currentSound.stopAsync()
      await currentSound.unloadAsync()
    }

    if(uri) 
    {
      await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({ playsInSilentModeIOS: true })

      const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync({ uri }, { shouldPlay: true }, FINISH_AUDIO)

      setCurrentSound(sound)
      await sound.playAsync()

      setPlayingIndex(index)
      setIsPlaying(true)
    } 
    else 
    {
      console.error('No sound URI found in AsyncStorage');
    }
  }

This works well for me to play audios that I record and store in my AsyncStorage, the problem is that I cannot detect when the audio ended, according to the documentation it should be able to be achieved with the FINISH_AUDIO function that has this
const FINISH_AUDIO = async(status: AVPlaybackStatus) =>
  {
    console.log(status)
    
    if(status.isLoaded)
    {
      if(status.didJustFinish)
      {
        setIsPlaying(false)
        setPlayingIndex(null)
        setCurrentSound(null)
      }
    }
  }

This function runs fine when the audio starts playing but doesn't go back in there when the audio has finished. Am I doing something wrong or am I missing some extra step?

Here is a related answer to this question, hope it helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/73095201/15831891

@Temidayo I had already seen that question before and I did everything that the documentation mentions and it still doesn't work, I can't get the status to return just when the sound ended
